# django rest_auth extend User with UserProfile

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I'm on django 1.7.5 with allauth and rest_auth.

Success on create a custom SignupForm with new field, but can't get value stored at signup time.

company_name is the field that is ignored, first and last name are stored...

1) rest_auth/forms.py

```
class SLCustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
""" in settings ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS='rest_auth.forms.SLCustomSignupForm' """

first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Nome')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Cognome')
company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Azienda')

def signup(self, request, user):
    """
    Invoked at signup time to complete the signup of the user.
    """
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.profilo_utente.company_name = self.cleaned_data['company_name']
    user.save()
```

in rest_auth/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress


class ProfiloUtente(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profilo_utente')
     company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "{}'s profile".format(self.user.username)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'profilo_utente'

def account_verified(self):
    if self.user.is_authenticated:
        result = EmailAddress.objects.filter(email=self.user.email)
        if len(result):
            return result[0].verified
    return False

User.profilo_utente = property(lambda u: ProfiloUtente.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I've modified the provided UserProfile model with ProfiloUtente, just to understand where and who would manage those data.

Accessing from shell:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
a = User.objects.get(username="myuser")
a.profilo_utente.company_name                  # see current value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add to a relation before the main object is saved, if the profiles are created in a signal they wont exist before the `user.save()`  call.

try

```
user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
user.save()     
user.profilo_utente.company_name = self.cleaned_data['company_name']
user.profilo_utente.save()
```